# excel - Division each number

Tags: excel

I have two columns A and B, the rows are also dynamic and their values.

```
+---+---+
| A | B |
+---+---+
| 2 | 4 |
| 5 | 6 |
|   | 2 |
|   | 8 |
+---+---+
```

How can I divide each value in column A with each column B value and show it one by one.
2/4
2/6
2/2
...
5/4
5/6
....

Thank you!

Comment: I am not really sure what you mean by showing value one by one, but you can create a division table, where A values will be rows and B values will be columns and then use mixed referencing formula for division.

Comment: fwiw and imho, this is just a case of bad spreadsheet design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This builds up a list of divisions in the C column with a loop through the list of values in the B column nested within a loop through the list of values in the A column.  I've assumed no empty spaces between values in either column.

```
Public Sub MyDivisions()
  dim iARow as integer, iBRow as integer, iCRow as integer
  iCRow = 0
  iARow = 0
  do while range("A1").offset(iARow) <> vbnullstring
    iBRow  = 0
    do while range("B1").offset(iBRow) <> vbnullstring
      range("C1").offset(iCRow) = range("A1").offset(iARow) & "/" & range("B1").offset(iBRow) & _
          " = " & range("A1").offset(iARow) / range("B1").offset(iBRow)
      iCRow = iCRow + 1
      iBRow = iBRow + 1
    loop
    iARow = iARow + 1
  loop
end sub
```

Simply add this to an object within your project and run it.  Disable events first if you have any code on your worksheet change event.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: *As far as StackOverflow is not a free-coding service, it is usually advised that such questions are closed, because they [do not comply with the rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).*

However, as far as it is somehow interesting, this is some code example, that does what you need to:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim rangeA As Range: Set rangeA = Range("A1:A2")
    Dim rangeB As Range: Set rangeB = Range("B1:B4")

    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim myCell2 As Range
    Dim myCell3 As Range

    Set myCell3 = Range("C1")

    For Each myCell In rangeA
        For Each myCell2 In rangeB
            myCell3 = myCell & " | " & myCell2
            myCell3.Offset(0, 1) = myCell / myCell2
            Set myCell3 = myCell3.Offset(1)
        Next myCell2
    Next myCell

End Sub
```

And this is what is produced in Excel:

[image]

TThe idea is that the code loops through the two given ranges writes on Column C what it is going to do and then puts the calculation inside column D.